# Have someone ever used the Avast RabbitMQ client? I got this error to resolve the dependency

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to use Avast RabbitMQ client and getting this error:

> [error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/avast/clients/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-client-core_2.13/8.0.1/rabbitmq-client-core_2.13-8.0.1.pom
>
> [error] (ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.avast.clients.rabbitmq:rabbitmq-client-core_2.13:8.0.1

This is the GitHub repo of the library:
https://github.com/avast/rabbitmq-scala-client

Comment: Please do not post text (errors and code) as images.

Comment: Try adding [bintray](https://bintray.com/) repository, it seems it is present [there](https://bintray.com/avast/maven/rabbitmq-scala-client/8.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem adding this to the build.sbt:

resolvers +=
"maven r2" at "https://dl.bintray.com/avast/maven/"